# How do I change the number of open files limit in Linux?

Tags: linux

When running my application I sometimes get an error about `too many files open`.

Running `ulimit -a` reports that the limit is 1024.  How do I increase the limit above 1024?

**Edit**
`ulimit -n 2048` results in a permission error.

Comment: see also:https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8949/231660

Comment: I just went through this on Centos 7 (same on RHEL) and made a blog post covering it because I had so much trouble even with all these posts: https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2018/12/21/centos7-and-rhel7-increasing-open-file-descriptors-process-limits/.  Often along with open files, you need to increase nproc which actually resides in multiple settings files... and if you use systemd/systemctl that has its own separate settings.  It's kind of nuts.

Comment: If you are using VSCode on linux this workaround might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55027686/1190948

Comment: a-bars closed this question while linus on GeeksForGeeks.com trying to figure this out also

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You could always try doing a `ulimit -n 2048`.  This will only reset the limit for your current shell and the number you specify must not exceed the hard limit

Each operating system has a different hard limit setup in a configuration file.  For instance, the hard open file limit on Solaris can be set on boot from /etc/system.

```
set rlim_fd_max = 166384
set rlim_fd_cur = 8192
```

On OS X, this same data must be set in /etc/sysctl.conf.

```
kern.maxfilesperproc=166384
kern.maxfiles=8192
```

Under Linux, these settings are often in /etc/security/limits.conf.

There are two kinds of limits:

- **soft** limits are simply the currently enforced limits
- **hard** limits mark the maximum value which cannot be exceeded by setting a soft limit

Soft limits could be set by any user while hard limits are changeable only by root.
Limits are a property of a process. They are inherited when a child process is created so system-wide limits should be set during the system initialization in init scripts and user limits should be set during user login for example by using pam_limits.

There are often defaults set when the machine boots.  So, even though you may reset your ulimit in an individual shell, you may find that it resets back to the previous value on reboot.  You may want to grep your boot scripts for the existence ulimit commands if you want to change the default.

Comment: can you tell me how to use this in windows?

Comment: @hoyhoy I can change it as `2048` but not as `4500` why? [see this](https://pasteboard.co/H0h6oJm.png)

Comment: @GaneshKrishnan what to add in the linux files that you have mentioned?

Comment: @Pritam Windows don’t have any `ulimit`. You must specify what you are using (e.g. WSL, Cygwin).

Answer (score 116):

If you are using Linux and you got the permission error, you will need to raise the allowed limit in the `/etc/limits.conf` or `/etc/security/limits.conf` file (where the file is located depends on your specific Linux distribution).

For example to allow anyone on the machine to raise their number of open files up to 10000 add the line to the `limits.conf` file.

`* hard nofile 10000`

Then logout and relogin to your system and you should be able to do:

`ulimit -n 10000`

without a permission error.

Comment: NOTE: Wildcard **does not** apply to `root` user. You have to specify `root hard nofile 10000` if you want to adjust the `root` limit.

Comment: @JoshPinter Haha, I just spent the past 3 hours or so going through every single tutorial on how to change the `ulimit` and finally found out I am logged in as root. That's why I kept seeing the 1024 in `ulimit -a`. I changed the wildcare, and added a `*` inside `limits.conf`. All is good now, (im using ssh keys don't worry :P) -- Thank you!!!

Comment: @NiCkNewman I'm glad you're laughing about it! That's a good trait in a programmer/sysops person. I did the same thing and wasn't so jovial. Glad it helped! :)

Comment: SUPLEMENT: You may find also a config in this dir: `/etc/security/limits.d/`.

Comment: I've opened /etc/security/limits.conf for the first time and noticed that everything is commented out there. What is the default value of "hard nofile" then?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu-18.04, I found that after making the changes in /etc/security/limits.conf , I had to RESTART the system then it worked.

Answer (score 41):

1) Add the following line to `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
webuser hard nofile 64000
```

then login as webuser

```
su - webuser
```

2) Edit following two files for webuser

append **.bashrc and .bash_profile** file by running

```
echo "ulimit -n 64000" >> .bashrc ; echo "ulimit -n 64000" >> .bash_profile
```

3) Log out, then log back in and verify that the changes have been made correctly:

```
$ ulimit -a | grep open
open files                      (-n) 64000
```

Thats it and them boom, boom boom.

Comment: If you get change your line in limits.conf from 'hard' to 'soft' it should become the new default and not require changes to bash profiles.

Comment: Seems you are repeating an extra steps. Setting limits alone will do the same as the profile, but across all sessions.

Answer (score 8):

If some of your services are balking into ulimits, it's sometimes easier to put appropriate commands into service's init-script. For example, when Apache is reporting

> [alert] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: apr_thread_create: unable to create worker thread

Try to put `ulimit -s unlimited` into `/etc/init.d/httpd`. This does not require a server reboot.