# Java IOException "Too many open files"

Tags: java, file-io

I'm doing some file I/O with multiple files (writing to 19 files, it so happens).  After writing to them a few hundred times I get the Java `IOException`: `Too many open files`.  But I actually have only a few files opened at once.  What is the problem here?  I can verify that the writes were successful.

Comment: Put a comment in the function that will open the files and verify that you are only opening each one one time.

Comment: How do you know that this error occurs because of one of these 19?  Java itself or the framework you're using might be opening files.

Comment: post your code.  Perhaps you are opening them inside a loop, so it happens repeatedly.

Comment: If you don't close the files yourself and just leave it to the garbage-collector to clean it up for you then it will take a long time for that to happen.  In the meantime, you're busy opening more files and before you know it, you've hit the limit.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

On Linux and other UNIX / UNIX-like platforms, the OS places a limit on the number of open file descriptors that a process may have at any given time.  In the old days, this limit used to be hardwired<sup>1</sup>, and relatively small.  These days it is much larger (hundreds / thousands), and subject to a "soft" per-process configurable resource limit.  (Look up the `ulimit` shell builtin ...)

Your Java application must be exceeding the per-process file descriptor limit.

You say that you have 19 files open, and that after a few hundred times you get an IOException saying "too many files open".  Now this particular exception can ONLY happen when a new file descriptor is requested; i.e. when you are *opening* a file (or a pipe or a socket).  You can *verify* this by printing the stacktrace for the IOException.

Unless your application is being run with a small resource limit (which seems unlikely), it follows that it must be repeatedly opening files / sockets / pipes, and failing to close them.  Find out why that is happening and you should be able to figure out what to do about it.

FYI, the following pattern is a safe way to write to files that is guaranteed not to leak file descriptors.

```
Writer w = new FileWriter(...);
try {
    // write stuff to the file
} finally {
    try {
        w.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Log error writing file and bail out.
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1 - Hardwired, as in compiled into the kernel.  Changing the number of available fd slots required a recompilation ... and could result in less memory being available for other things.  In the days when Unix commonly ran on 16-bit machines, these things really mattered.</sup>

**UPDATE**

The Java 7 way is more concise:

```
try (Writer w = new FileWriter(...)) {
    // write stuff to the file
} // the `w` resource is automatically closed
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Apparently you can also encounter a "too many files open" while attempting to run an external program.  The basic cause is as described above.  However, the reason that you encounter this in `exec(...)` is that the JVM is attempting to create "pipe" file descriptors that will be connected to the external application's standard input / output / error.

Comment: I would recommend to use [IOUtils.closeQuietly()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.io.Writer))

Comment: I would use that too.  But I wouldn't recommend adding that dependency JUST to get a method that you can write yourself in 2 minutes.

Comment: Indeed, in 2016 I would strongly recommend using *try with resources*; i.e.  the "Java 7 way".  If you are still using Java 6 or earlier, you should upgrade.  Java 6 has been out of maintenance for 4 years now.

Comment: I felt so happy when i read on the IOUtils documentation page about the closeQuietly(Closeable... closeables) method, which says, `"Deprecated. As of 2.6 removed without replacement. Please use the try-with-resources statement or handle suppressed exceptions manually."`

Comment: @computingfreak - Yea.  As of Java 7, you shouldn't need to `close()` explicitly anymore.  The `IOUtils` deprecation is simply trying to get to do things in a more modern way ... and be happier.  See my first UPDATE.

Answer (score 8):

For UNIX:

As Stephen C has suggested, changing the maximum file descriptor value to a higher value avoids this problem.

Try looking at your present file descriptor capacity:

```
   $ ulimit -n
```

Then change the limit according to your requirements.

```
   $ ulimit -n <value>
```

Note that this just changes the limits in the current shell and any child / descendant process.  To make the change "stick" you need to put it into the relevant shell script or initialization file.

Comment: It only avoids the problem until your application hits the new higher limit.  IMO, this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You're obviously not closing your file descriptors before opening new ones. Are you on windows or linux?

Comment: If he indeed opens 19 files, and has an array with the file descriptors, then he should be fine, but I think he is actually opening up more than he thinks he does.

Comment: AFAIK, Windows doesn't have this issue; for e.g. on my XP SP3, I was able to traverse the entire source tree of CXF (around 15K) files without a sweat without closing any of the files opened.

Comment: I guarantee windows has a file descriptor limit. It just may default to 65000

Answer (score 2):

Although in most general cases the error is quite clearly that file handles have not been closed, I just encountered an instance with JDK7 on Linux that well... is sufficiently ****ed up to explain here.

The program opened a FileOutputStream (fos), a BufferedOutputStream (bos) and a DataOutputStream (dos). After writing to the dataoutputstream, the dos was closed and I thought everything went fine.

Internally however, the dos, tried to flush the bos, which returned a Disk Full error. That exception was eaten by the DataOutputStream, and as a consequence the underlying bos was not closed, hence the fos was still open.

At a later stage that file was then renamed from (something with a .tmp) to its real name. Thereby, the java file descriptor trackers lost track of the original .tmp, yet it was still open !

To solve this, I had to first flush the DataOutputStream myself, retrieve the IOException and close the FileOutputStream myself.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. `DataOutputStream` does not swallow exceptions. `FilterOutputStream.close()` does, but not in a way that would suppress the close. The part about the 'Java file descriptor trackers', whatever they might be, 'los[ing] track of the original .tmp' is devoid of ascertainable meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this in automated tests: it's best to properly close all files between test runs.

If you're not sure which file(s) you have left open, a good place to start is the "open" calls which are throwing exceptions!

If you have a file handle should be open exactly as long as its parent object is alive, you could add a `finalize` method on the parent that calls close on the file handle. And call `System.gc()` between tests.

Answer (score -7):

Recently, I had a program batch processing files, I have certainly closed each file in the loop, but the error still there.

And later, I resolved this problem by garbage collect eagerly every hundreds of files:

```
int index;
while () {
    try {
        // do with outputStream...
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
    if (index++ % 100 = 0)
        System.gc();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are mistaken.  You may *think* that you closed all streams explicitly, but somewhere in your program there is a execution path that results in streams not being closed.  Running the GC is causing the "lost" streams to be finalized.  Stream finalization calls `this.close()` (IIRC).

Comment: Good to know though that gc() closes streams.

Comment: @StefanReich It doesn't. It closes file descriptors. Streams will remain unflushed.