# Exception getting while migration of alfresco content, Too many open files

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis

I am getting this error while migrating content from one alfresco repository to other.

And I am getting this error on live production server logs.

And also Server is getting down while migration is running.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue or any suggestion is there to avoid this issue.

Any help or comments will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

I have written below code snippet

```
ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl("content." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName),
            BigInteger.valueOf(fileName.length()), new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(newfile), doc.getContentStream().getStream());
```

I have 2 repositorys,Using above code I am reading content stream from source and creating new file in target repository and adding the content stream.  But I didn't found any way to to close the content stream.

Please find below error log for more details.

java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Too Many Open Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289447/java-too-many-open-files)

Comment: Actually I am using CMIS API, and there I am not using any writter object

Comment: Sorry, but your question wasn't clear enaough for me. I wasn't sure that you knew what a "too many open file issue is". Could you explain what you mean by migration and what you exactly do  ? Could you monitor your system open files, to see if you have a leak, or just that your migration mecanism is using too many system ressources ?

Comment: You've tagged your question with "dotcmis", but your code snippet is Java, not .Net. I guess, the tag should be "opencmis".

Comment: You are providing the wrong length in your code snippet. It should be the length of the stream, not the length of the file name.

Comment: Sorry @FlorianMüller  mystically it out dotcmis tag, now I have edited. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your CMIS query? Have you tried limiting it to work on smaller sets of data, in multiple passes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the DotCMIS method `GetContentStream` on the client side, make sure you always close the stream - even if you are not reading it. Otherwise, the socket to the server stays open. Depending on your application the client and/or the server can run out of sockets.

Closing the stream works like this:

```
IContentStream contentStream = document.GetContentStream();
Stream stream = contentStream.Stream;

... do something with the stream ...

stream.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks @Florian Muller  This is what I am doing. Can you please help me with closing the stream. Because I tried at my level but I ditn't found any way to close the stream.

Comment: @DeepakTalape please share your code in your question.