# Fixing too many open files Exception(I am using try-catch-finally)

Tags: java, linux, sockets, exception, connection-pooling

I have web service written on JAVA (version 1.8) which connects HSM and sends/receives data via socket. My application is deployed on `Apache Tomcat/8.5.14` on `linux`.

Although I'm closing socket connection properly I have

> java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

and here is myclass

```
public class myClass implements AutoCloseable {
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream in;
    DataOutputStream out;

    public myClass(String ip, int port) throws Exception {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception("Connecting to HSM failed" + e);
        }
    }       

   public String sendCommandToHsm(String command) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(command);
        out.flush();
        return in.readUTF();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                lgg.info("Closing of socket failed", e);
            }
        }

        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                lgg.info("Closing of inputStream failed", e);
            }
        }

        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                lgg.info("Closing of outputStream failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is using of my class

```
try (MyClass myClass = new MyClass(ip, port);) {
      myClass.sendCommandToHsm("my command");
 }
```

I increased maximum open files limit on server from default value(1024) to 8192 and few times later the same `Exception` occurred again.

I'm thinking about creating `Socket Connection Pool`, is it good idea?

Can you suggest any other solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Too Many Open Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289447/java-too-many-open-files)

Comment: Don't forget that both files and sockets count for the ulimit. Don't have too many processes running on the same unix account, especially if they open many sockets. Check the limit with your OS command (I got that issue while running Weblogic on AIX, so you can't really reuse it) and where those sockets connect to using netstat or a similar tool.

Comment: Does your HSM really understand `writeUTF()`? Hard to believe. And why are you using a new connection per message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Although I'm closing socket connection properly ...

It looks like you are, but I think there are a couple of problems.  (I don't know that these are the cause of your leak, but the first one is a plausible explanation.)

### Problem 1.

```
public myClass(String ip, int port) throws Exception {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("Connecting to HSM failed" + e);
    }
}
```

If an exception is thrown during setup of the streams, then the socket will be leaked.

### Problem 2.

```
public void close() {
    if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            lgg.info("Closing of socket failed", e);
        }
    }

    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            lgg.info("Closing of inputStream failed", e);
        }
    }

    if (out != null) {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            lgg.info("Closing of outputStream failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

You are closing in the wrong order.  You should<sup>1</sup> close `in` and `out` before closing `socket`.  In particular, if `out` has buffered data, then closing `out` will attempt to flush ... which will fail if you have closed `socket` already.

Also if `socket.close()` or `in.close()` fails for some other reason than an `IOException`, then the subsequent closes will be skipped.  So you should use a `finally` here.

Also the `isClosed()` call is redundant.  Calling `close()` on a resource that is already closed should do nothing.  This is part of the contract of `close()`.

Finally, calling `close()` on a socket should<sup>2</sup> automatically close the low-level file descriptors beneath `in` and `out`.  So it is arguably best to just do this:

```
public void close() {
    if (socket != null) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            lgg.info("Closing of socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If this doesn't fix your leaks, I suggest that you use `netstat` and `lsof` to try to find out if the leakage is open files or open sockets.

---

> I'm thinking about creating Socket Connection Pool, is it good idea?

Yes ... if you can find an existing (well designed and tested) library that meets your requirements.  Implementing a reliable pool from scratch is not trivial.

But note:

1. An incorrectly implemented (or used) pool can leak file descriptors.
2. The server-side needs to be able to cope with a series of requests / replied on the same connection.
3. If you have too many simultaneous open connections to *different* places, then the pool needs a way to close some of them ...

---

<sup>1 - It is debatable whether you should close `out` before `in`.  On the one hand, closing `out` flushes outstanding data to the server.  On the other hand, by the time that `myClass.close()` has been called there won't be anything reading the server's response.  And besides, the `sendCommandToHsm` method flushes ... so there shouldn't be any outstanding data.</sup>

<sup>2 - The javadoc for `Socket.close()` says: *"Closing this socket will also close the socket's `InputStream` and `OutputStream`."*</sup>

Comment: He should close `out` first, so it can be flushed, and `socket` in the `finally` block of that close. He need not close `in` at all.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about his `close()` method, yes that is correct.

Comment: Well I'm really talking in a confused way about the `try` block enclosing `out.close()`. I'm specifically commenting on 'you should close `in` and `out`', which is at best back to front.

Comment: Well, yeah, and if you completely understand the semantics of your application there isn't necessarily a need to close `in` *or* `out` either; just the socket. You can't have it both ways. *As a general rule*, which is what you seem to be stating, you should close the outermost stream or writer wrapped around the socket output stream. That way you can never be wrong.