# reading multiple files in fortran

Tags: fortran

I have hundreds of files with file name fort.1, fort.2, fort.3 and so on until fort.5000.
What I want is to open each file and operate that file and close. Then go on with next file. I want to do this in Fortran 90.

I have browsed but could not get what I want. I saw one thread [for opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611360/opening-multiple-files-in-fortran-90) but it doesn't help me much.

I tried writing `

```
program openFile
IMPLICIT none
INTEGER(I-N), REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
real,dimension(2000) :: angle           
CHARACTER(len=10) FN
integer::I, k
integer,parameter :: N=102  
DO I=101,N
!WRITE(FN,10) I
!WRITE(6,*) FN
OPEN(1,FILE=FN)
do k=1,200
read(1,'(F8.3)') angle(k)
print*,
end do      
CLOSE(1)
enddo 
10 FORMAT(5Hfort.I3)
STOP
END
```

`
But seems it doesn't work. Is that possible me getting some help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you realise you have commented out the key line setting the file name. also the format here only works for 3 digit numbers, not to mention using the archaic h descriptor

Comment: Try to see some example programs in some book or internet tutorial and use some formatting for your programs. You will be able to orientate better in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach is to create the filename in a string.   For your style of names:

```
write (filename, '("fort.", I0)' )  FileNum
```

Then open each file using the filename, as you are doing.

A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048441/writing-files-in-fortran-with-increasing-numbers