# Fortran get new filename

Tags: file, fortran

I want get new file in Fortran with extension (.for), for example:
p12.12332.txt

I make:

```
CHARACTER filename*20
REAL tmp = 12.12332
filename = 'p00000000.txt'
write(filename(2:9),'(F12.5)') tmp
```

but I can not get file, I get

```
Fortran runtime error: End of record
```

What's problem?
How can I file "p12.12332.txt" via Fortran?

Comment: What do you mean that you "get nothing"?  Note, though, that you are trying to write a field of width 12 to a character substring of length 10.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for how to write to an internal record?

Comment: To a substring length 8 actually. You should use F8.5. You should better descibe your result. What is "nothing"? Is there any error message or something? (I expect your filename to contain `p********.txt`)

Comment: Other than that it is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262695/converting-integers-to-strings-in-fortran http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250123/reading-multiple-files-in-fortran?lq=1 and others. Just use the right format.

Comment: I didn't mean we should actually close it as a duplicate. It is strange to close it as a duplicate of converting integers, when there are no integers in this questions.

Comment: I agree with @vladimirf: my close vote was as a typo as the main problem of the question is solved by changing `12` to `8`.  As the answer given says, there are other necessary things for usability, but that possibly requires the question to be in a different form

Answer (score 1):

> I get nothing,

you say. What I get are runtime errors.

- `Fortran runtime error: End of record` for **gfortran**
- `forrtl: severe (66): output statement overflows record` for **ifort**

That's because you're trying to write 12 characters into an 8 character buffer.

The first thing you can do is to correct the length:

```
write(filename(2:9), '(F8.5)') tmp
```

But this will cause unexpected behaviour if `tmp < 10`: It will have a space between the p and the number, like so: `p 2.12332.txt`

I think it would be better if you constructed the whole file name anew every time:

```
write(filename, '("p", F0.5, ".txt")') tmp
write(filename, '(A1, F0.5, A4)') "p", tmp, ".txt"
```

(Either one of these will work.)

This will change the length of the file name:

```
p12.23321.txt
p2.23321.txt
```

Otherwise you'll have to try with leading zeros, which is described here:
[How to pad FORTRAN floating point output with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886390/how-to-pad-fortran-floating-point-output-with-leading-zeros)