# How to open and read multiple files in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have some issues about opening and reading multiple files. I have to write a code which reads two columns in n files formatted in the same way (they are different only for the values...). Before this, I open another input file and an output file in which I will write my results. I read other questions in this forum ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611360/opening-multiple-files-in-fortran-90)) and tried to do the same thing, but I receive these errors:

```
 read(fileinp,'(I5)') i-49
                   1
 devstan.f90:20.24:

 fileLoop : do i = 50,52
                    2
 Error: Variable 'i' at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
```

and

```
 read(fileinp,'(I5)') i-49
           1
 Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

My files are numbered from 1 to n and are named 'lin*27-n.dat' (where n is the index starts from 1) and the code is:

```
 program deviation
  implicit none

  character(len=15) :: filein,fileout,fileinp
  integer :: row,i,h
  real :: usv,usf,tsv,tsf,diff


  write(*,'(2x,''Input file .......''/)')
  read(*,'(a12)') filein
  write(*,'(2x,''Output file........''/)')
  read(*,'(a12)') fileout
  open(unit = 30,File=filein)
  open(unit = 20,File=fileout)


  fileLoop : do i = 50,52
  fileinp = 'lin*27-'
  read(fileinp,'(I5)') i-49
  open(unit = i,File=fileinp)


   do row = 1,24
    read(30,*) h,usv,tsv
    read(i,*)  h,usf,tsf

     diff = usf - usv

    write(20,*) diff
   enddo
   close(i)
  enddo fileLoop

 end program deviation
```

How can I solve it? I am not pro in Fortran, so please don't use difficult language, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The troublesome line is

```
read(fileinp,'(I5)') i-49
```

You surely mean to do a `write` (as in the example linked): this `read` statement attempts to read *from* the variable `fileinp` rather than writing to it.

That said, simply replacing with `write` is probably not what you need either.  This will ignore the previous line

```
fileinp = 'lin*27-'
```

merely setting to, in turn, "1", "2", "3" (with leading blanks).  Something like (assuming you intend that `*` to be there)

```
write(fileinp, '("lin*27-",I1)') i-49
```

Note also the use of `I1` in the format, rather than `I5`: one may want to avoid blanks in the filename.  [This is suitable when there is exactly one digit; look up `Iw.m` and `I0` when generalizing.]

Comment: thanks francescalus, but if my input files are 'lin*27-1' is it only necessary to change I5.5 into I1? because at runtime i receive this error:
At line 28 of file devstan.f90 (unit = 50, file = 'lin*27-00001')
Fortran runtime error: End of file