# Limit of connected sockets boost::asio

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio

I have a problem, i use boost::asio for my server listener implementation, but using boost::asio when count connected sockets > 1000-1100 i have an error - "Too many opened files"

How can i fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: That is likely platform-specific (eg. you could be hitting a soft limit, or a hard system limit, or simply exhausting some resource). Please describe your platform (OS etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a boost::asio problem. This is an OS-level problem. Try doing `ulimit -a` on the command line and you'll see there's a limit for 'open files'. This is the number of file descriptors a process is allowed to own. It can be changed, but it's the reason you're getting the error.

This stack overflow question "[How do I change the number of open files limit in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux)" talks about how this limit can be changed. The short answer is that it's not particularly simple to do. It's an OS-level configuration parameter.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the client side. This is what is surprising to me. Because I'm only running at most 3 concurrent socket at  a time but I still get "Too many files open error"  when I try to create the 3. socket. I check the limit and it was 1024 files. Since this problem starts to occur around 6 hours later than client start time, I suspect I'm not actually destroying the socket obj after I'm done. But isn't is automatically get destroyed when gone out of scope? Because I'm not explicitly calling the destructor.