# Massconnect loss of attribute socket

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, autobahn

I am running the `massconnect.py` module in order to simulate opening many parallel web-socket connections, but when I try to open 15000 connections (specified in massconnect json) after some time I get the following error message:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\log.py", line 88, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\log.py", line 73, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\reactor.py", line 120, in _callEventCallback
    evt.callback(rc, bytes, evt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\iocpreactor\tcp.py", line 285, in cbConnect
    self.socket.setsockopt(
exceptions.AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'socket'
```

Opening of web-socket connections is interrupted, and I get this exception.

I adapted my `massconnect.py` module to confirm web-socket authentication for the app. I am testing so that each time a client is allocated it sends a unique auth message.

I already set `MaxUserPort` in the registry to 65534. I thought that problem might cause me to run out of memory, but after inspecting with different machines I realised that that this is not the cause.

Is this maybe a known python/twisted issue?

@Glyph:

Here is massconnect.py source code:

```
'''
Created on Jan 29, 2013

@author: boro.petrovic
'''
###############################################################################
##
##  Copyright 2011,2012 Tavendo GmbH
##
##  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
##  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
##  You may obtain a copy of the License at
##
##      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
##
##  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
##  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
##  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
##  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
##  limitations under the License.
##
###############################################################################

import sys
import time
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import error
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred, returnValue, inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.interfaces import IReactorTime
from autobahn.websocket import connectWS
from autobahn.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol
import time

f='start'

class MassConnectProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):   

    def sendHello(self, message):
        #self.sendMessage("Hello from Python!")
        self.sendMessage(payload=message)
        #reactor.callLater(2, self.sendHello(message='test'))

    def onOpen(self):
        global f
        wstoken = f.readline().rstrip()
        message = 'messagecontent'+wstoken
        self.factory.test.onConnected()
        self.sendHello(message)
        self.wstoken = wstoken

    def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
        print "Got message from wstoken " + self.wstoken + " :" + msg

class MassConnectFactory(WebSocketClientFactory):

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        if self.test.onFailed():
            reactor.callLater(float(self.retrydelay)/1000., connector.connect)

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        if self.test.onLost():
            reactor.callLater(float(self.retrydelay)/1000., connector.connect)

class MassConnect:

    def __init__(self, name, uri, connections, batchsize, batchdelay, retrydelay):
        self.name = name
        self.uri = uri
        self.batchsize = batchsize
        self.batchdelay = batchdelay
        self.retrydelay = retrydelay
        self.failed = 0
        self.lost = 0
        self.targetCnt = connections
        self.currentCnt = 0
        self.actual = 0

    def run(self):
        self.d = Deferred()
        self.started = time.clock()
        self.connectBunch()
        return self.d

    def onFailed(self):
        self.failed += 1
        return True

    def onLost(self):
        self.lost += 1
        return True

    def onConnected(self):
        #sprint "connect"
        self.actual += 1
        if self.actual % self.batchsize == 0:
            sys.stdout.write(".")
        if self.actual == self.targetCnt:
            self.ended = time.clock()
            duration = self.ended - self.started
            print " connected %d clients to %s at %s in %s seconds (retries %d = failed %d + lost %d)" % (self.currentCnt, self.name, self.uri, duration, self.failed + self.lost, self.failed, self.lost)
            try:
                reactor.run()
            except twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyRunning:
                pass

            result = {'name': self.name,
                  'uri': self.uri,
                  'connections': self.targetCnt,
                  'retries': self.failed + self.lost,
                  'lost': self.lost,
                  'failed': self.failed,
                  'duration': duration}
            self.d.callback(result)

    def connectBunch(self):

        if self.currentCnt + self.batchsize < self.targetCnt:
            c = self.batchsize
            redo = True
        else:
            c = self.targetCnt - self.currentCnt
            redo = False
        for i in xrange(0, c):
            factory = MassConnectFactory(self.uri, origin=None, protocols=[("myprotocol")])
            factory.test = self
            factory.retrydelay = self.retrydelay
            factory.protocol = MassConnectProtocol
            factory.setProtocolOptions(version=13)
            factory.setSessionParameters(url="myurl", origin=None, protocols=["myprotocol"])
            connectWS(factory)
            self.currentCnt += 1
        if redo:
            reactor.callLater(float(self.batchdelay)/1000., self.connectBunch)

class MassConnectTest:

    def __init__(self, spec):
        global f
        f = open("C:/tokens.txt", "r")
        self.spec = spec

    @inlineCallbacks
    def run(self):
        global f
        res = []
        for s in self.spec['servers']:
            t = MassConnect(s['name'],
                            s['uri'],
                            self.spec['options']['connections'],
                            self.spec['options']['batchsize'],
                            self.spec['options']['batchdelay'],
                            self.spec['options']['retrydelay'])
            r = yield t.run()
            res.append(r)
        returnValue(res)
        f.close()
```

In script i replaced confidential data with dummy strings.

From token.txt file i am reading authentication tokens foe each of 15000 users i am connecting to application under test via web-socket. 
This way i simulate connection of many different users and for each of them i have active independent web socket connection.

Unfortunately i did not reach the point where i have all 15000 connections established because while running the script (making connections) i got Unhandled Error message.

Comment: Please include the source of `massconnect.py`.

Comment: @Glyph , I 'm sorry for disturbing you but would you like to look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318976/how-to-use-massconnect-py-properly)?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you reduced `massconnect.py` to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  However, if the problem is cropping up only at the level of multiple thousands of concurrent connections, you are probably running out of file descriptors (sorry Twisted's error message for this is not great).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux) for some information about changing this parameter in your operating system.