# Python dictionary too full or something else?

Tags: python, dictionary, h5py

I have about 1300 h5 files to sort into a dictionary using h5py. When I run my code on about 250 files it works fine, but any amount larger gives me the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "solution_script.py", line 31, in <module>
    File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 165, in __init__
    File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 57, in make_fid
    File "h5f.pyx", line 70, in h5py.h5f.open (h5py/h5f.c:1626)
  IOError: unable to open file (File accessability: Unable to open file)'
```

I'm not sure if I set up the dictionary incorrectly or if there is a better way to do this.

Here's my code if anyone can see some obvious mistakes I've made:

```
nodesDictionary = {}
velDictionary = {}
cellsDictionary={}
num_h5file = -1;
for root, directory, files in os.walk(rootDirectory):
    for file in sorted(files):
        if file.endswith(".h5"):
            num_h5file = num_h5file + 1
                curh5file = h5py.File(file, 'r')
                nodes_list = curh5file["nodes"]
                cells_list = curh5file["cells"]
                velocity_list = curh5file["velocity"]
                for i in range(0, len(nodes_list)-1):
                    if num_h5file not in nodesDictionary:
                            nodesDictionary[num_h5file] = [curh5file["nodes"][i]]
                            velDictionary[num_h5file] = [curh5file["velocity"][i]]                         
                    else:
                            nodesDictionary[num_h5file].append(curh5file["nodes"][i])
                            velDictionary[num_h5file].append(curh5file["velocity"][i])
                for j in range(0, len(cells_list)-1):
                    if num_h5file not in cellsDictionary:
                            cellsDictionary[num_h5file] = [curh5file["cells"][j]]
                    else:
                            cellsDictionary[num_h5file].append(curh5file["cells"][j])
```

Any help/advice/insight would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @reptilicus that your best bet is to close the files you aren't actively using if possible.  But if you really must, you can use the [ulimit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ulimit) command to increase the number of open files available to your process - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux) for details

**Edit:**

You can use [context management](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to ensure the file is closed even if an error occurs:

```
with h5py.File(file, 'r') as curh5file:
    ... # Do your stuff

... # continue other actions
```

When you exit the "with" block, the file will be automatically closed.  If an exception happens, it will still be closed.

Comment: Great! I will see what closing files after opening does.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to close the files when you are done working on them, there is a limit in the OS on how many files you can open at a time.

At the end of your block where you open the h5 file, just put in a close statement and all should be well. Something like:

```
curh5file = h5py.File(file, 'r')
...do some stuff
curh5file.close()
```