# Why changes to /etc/limits doesn't work

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, coredump, rootfs

I am trying to provide support for core dump on my ARM based target ,I have read about both /etc/limits and /etc/security/limits.conf ,My target file system doesn't have the later one on to it ,So I have made below changes to /etc/limits

```
root C100000
```

After adding this line to /etc/limits was expecting the generation of core file but ulimit -a shows me

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0

Why these changes into /etc/limits does not at all reflecting.

Now what should I have to do ?

Do I have to add /etc/security/limits.conf to my filesystem??

I am not looking at option of using setrlimit().

Comment: I guess you need to logout and login again to have this working. Did you do so?

Comment: @fedorqui I rebooted the target board,Do I missing something??

Comment: To be honest I don't know if that works. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux , maybe you find something that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everone for the help you did to me,The way I solved this problem is to set following defaults in /etc/systemd/system.conf

```
 DefaultLimitCORE=infinity  
 DumpCore=yes
```

This file was already there in my filesystem and it generates core dump for process started from login Shell as well as process started from systemd .

Below given thread is quite useful and is source of reference for me.

http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2013-February/009174.html

Comment: Great! That is exactly that I was looking