# My spring+hibernate app does not closes jdbc connections

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc

I have an Spring+Hibernate+Tomcat+MySql application in production, I'm running into a problem. I think the application is not closing it's jdbc connections, and when it reaches its limits (currently 200), the application stop responding, and I have to restart tomcat. Do I need to close this connections somewhere ? Here is my Datasource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/" override="true" reloadable="false" swallowOutput="false">
    <!-- jdbcInterceptors, removeAbandoned, removeAbandonedTimeout van juntos, ver http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/01/24/using-tomcat-7-jdbc-\
    connection-pool-production, y https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html -->
    <!-- removeAbandonedTimeout es en segundos -->

    <Resource name="jdbc/catWDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
              url="@URL@"
              username="@USERNAME@"
              password="@PASSWORD@"

              maxActive="200"
              maxIdle="50"
              minIdle="10"
              suspectTimeout="60"
              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
              minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"

              validationQuery="select 1"
              validationInterval="30000"
              testOnBorrow="true"

              removeAbandoned="true"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
              abandonWhenPercentageFull="10"
              maxWait="10000"

              jdbcInterceptors="ResetAbandonedTimer;StatementFinalizer"


            />

</Context>
```

And here is an image of the appdynamics monitoring the connections, from 3 days until now

[image: app Dynamics image]

Here is a excerpt of the error I get on the catalina.out log file:

> **type Exception report**
>
> message Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open
>   connection
>
> **description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception**
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open
>   connection
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:932)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
>   javax.servlet.http. . . .
>
> **root cause**
>
> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open
>   connection
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager. . . .
>
> **root cause**
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   ***Too many connections***
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor67.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.

**UPDATE**

```
public Category findByIdByApp(Integer id, int appListId) throws DataAccessException {

       Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Category.class,"category")
                .createAlias("appList", "app")
                .add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("category.categoryId", id), Restrictions.eq("app.appListId", appListId)));
          List result=criteria.list();

        if(result.size()==1)

                return (Category) result.get(0);
         else
                return null;
    }
```

The Category domain object is mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Comparable, Serializable {
```

So my guess is, taking mithridas comments into account, that I´m using the hibernate  session´s manually, And I would need to close them with something like this:

```
this.getSession().clear();
```

Or i could implement @PersistenceContext. 
Would anyone direct me to this implementations so I can evaluate which is best for us to use ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE2:**
Added more info in answer to James Massey comment:

These are my: datasource, sessionFactory, transactionManager, and categoryDAO sessionFactory assignment:

```
<!-- ========================= DATA ACCESS OBJECT DEFINITIONS ======================== -->

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/catWDB</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">1</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<!---->
<bean id="transactionManager" lazy-init="true"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>

</bean>



<bean id="categoryDAOTarget" class="com.bamboo.catW3.DAO.impl.CategoryDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: How do you open/close your Hibernate sessions? Do you use `@PersistenceContext` to obtain `EntityManager` from Spring or open/close your Hibernate sessions manually? If you're opening your Hibernate sessions manually, you do need to close it yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure, since the original designer of that part of the application left, I thought we used this class in the AOP configuration to handle that: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean , But I don't know how to check what you ask. Would you help me on that ? thank you.

Comment: Check if there are any Hibernate `Session` objects used manually, such as `Session sess = factory.openSession();`

Comment: Thank you mithridas, you're comment are very useful, I updated the question base on your comment, since it´s too much information.

Comment: Can you post your session factory and transaction manager configuration's. Or are you not using Spring's Session Factory and Transaction Manager? The pitfalls of not using these objects is that manually managing sessions is hard, and prone to issues like the one you've described. If you are using these objects, then it's a problem with your configuration.

Comment: Thank you James Massey, I posted my sessionfactory and transaction manager configuration below the UPDATE 2 subtitle. Your feedback is very valuable to us.

Comment: How do your jdbc connections compare to the server connections in your server.xml file - trying to compare the ratio of jdbc to server connections for to compare metrics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem did not lay in the sessions but in the connection pool, sessions where being managed correctly, but the connection pool in the JDBC layer wasn't closing the connections.

These are the things that I did to fix them.

**JDBC context configuration**

1.- Changed the JDBC connection factory from tomcat's old BasicDataSourceFactory to tomcat's new DataSourceFactory

2.-  Tuned the JDBC settings based on this article: 
http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency

**Session factory xml configuration**

3.- Deleted this line from the session factory configuration:

```
<prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">1</prop>
```

This is how my configuration ended up:

**JDBC context configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/" override="true" reloadable="false" swallowOutput="false">
    <Resource name="jdbc/catWDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              url="@URL@"
              username="@USERNAME@"
              password="@PASSWORD@"
              maxActive="200"
              maxIdle="50"
              minIdle="10"
              suspectTimeout="60"
              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
              minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              validationInterval="30000"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              removeAbandoned="true"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
              abandonWhenPercentageFull="10"
              maxWait="10000"
              jdbcInterceptors="ResetAbandonedTimer;StatementFinalizer"
            />
</Context>
```

**Session factory xml configuration**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: How do your jdbc connections compare to the server connections in your server.xml file - trying to compare the ratio of jdbc to server connections for to compare metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `@PersistenceContext` annotation to obtain `EntityManager` from Spring context and `@Transactional` annotation to drive your transactions. This way you won't need to worry about closing Hibernate sessions manually, and number of connections will not increase until there are *too many connections*.

Comment: Thank you mithridas, I will try your suggestion using this article: http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-jpa.jsp, and come back after testing in production.

Comment: Hello, I added your suggestions, but it turns out the problem did not lay in the sessions but in the connection pool, sessions where being managed correctly, but the connection pool in the jdbc layer wasn't closing the connections.