# connect ECONNREFUSED in NODEJS

Tags: node.js

I get an error when I run file example4.js that test another file example3.js.

This is my code:

```
**//file example 3**

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// write out numbers
function writeNumbers(res) {

    var counter = 0;

    // increment global, write to client
    for (var i = 0; i<100; i++) {
        counter++;
        res.write(counter.toString() + '\n');
    }
}

// create http server
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var query = require('url').parse(req.url).query;
    var app = require('querystring').parse(query).file + ".txt";

    // content header
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    // write out numbers
    writeNumbers(res);

    // timer to open file and read contents
    setTimeout(function() {

        console.log('opening ' + app);
        // open and read in file contents
        fs.readFile(app, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err)
                res.write('Could not find or open file for reading\n');
            else {
                res.write(data);
            }
            // reponse is done
            res.end();
        });
    },2000);
}).listen(8382);

console.log('Server running at 8124/');


**//end of example 3**

**//file example 4**

var http = require('http');

//The url we want, plus the path and options we need
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8124,
    path: '/?file=secondary',
    method: 'GET'
};

var processPublicTimeline = function(response) {
    // finished? ok, write the data to a file
    console.log('finished request');
};

for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    // make the request, and then end it, to close the connection
    http.request(options, processPublicTimeline).end();
}
```

**The error is:**

```
events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
Process finished with exit code 8
```

There are an attachment with relevant files ( I've included 2 files in one).
Does anybody know what a problem?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are exceeding the OS's limit on concurrent open file descriptors because your client code attempts to open 2000 concurrent connections. Try using the [ulimit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645/266795) utility to increase

Answer (score 0):

In the code, your server is listening at port no:8382 and your client is trying to connect to port no:8124 where there is no server listening for the client. So, You are getting the ECONNREFUSED.