# web app on machine (on local computer works correctly)

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an error:

```
 Exception in thread "TCPSelector" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/net4j/channel/ChannelException
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPAcceptor.createConnector(TCPAcceptor.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPAcceptor.handleAccept(TCPAcceptor.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPSelector.handleSelection(TCPSelector.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPSelector.run(TCPSelector.java:179)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.net4j.channel.ChannelException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    ... 5 more
Exception in thread "TCPSelector" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.internal.net4j.buffer.Buffer.write(Buffer.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPConnector.handleWrite(TCPConnector.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPSelector.handleSelection(TCPSelector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPSelector.run(TCPSelector.java:179)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.init(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.<clinit>(FileDispatcherImpl.java:35)
    ... 9 more

Exception in thread "TCPSelector" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.internal.net4j.buffer.Buffer.write(Buffer.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPConnector.handleWrite(TCPConnector.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPSelector.handleSelection(TCPSelector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.net4j.internal.tcp.TCPSelector.run(TCPSelector.java:179)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On local computer (local tomcat) it works fine. On machine I have this error. I'm confused, because I don't have any ideas why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your operating system has run out of file descriptors:

```
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
```

if you are running on linux [have a look at the ulimit command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux)