# Getting Error 7 Argument list too long for more option?

Tags: python, unix, command-line, subprocess

I have written some code in python to display list of data using more option in Unix command shell. If the data is lengthy the below command is failed. Could anyone please suggest me the solution for this.

```
subprocess.call(['echo "'+str(output)+'" | more'], shell=True)
```

Error :

```
[Errno 7] Argument list too long
```

Expected Output

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
n
More
```

-

Comment: I think it's related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650841/why-am-i-getting-errno-7-argument-list-too-long-and-oserror-errno-24-too-ma

Comment: What is the size of output variable?