# Nodeweb kit crashes - Events.js:85 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-webkit

So I'm currently using a node webkit and express to run an application on a raspberry pi, however after leaving it on for a while it just crashes with the error:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^ Error: bind ENFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at dgram.js:224:28
    at dns.js:85:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Can anybody give me some pointers or knows whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've hit the maximum number of allowed files/sockets open.

See this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux) for more info.

Comment: You sir have save me a lot of time, thanks for the link!