# Why redis can not set maximum open file

Tags: redis

```
1167:M 26 Apr 13:00:34.666 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
1167:M 26 Apr 13:00:34.667 # Redis can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
1167:M 26 Apr 13:00:34.667 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
1167:M 26 Apr 13:00:34.685 # Creating Server TCP listening socket 192.34.62.56​​:6379: Name or service not known
1135:M 26 Apr 20:34:24.308 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
1135:M 26 Apr 20:34:24.309 # Redis can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
1135:M 26 Apr 20:34:24.309 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
1135:M 26 Apr 20:34:24.330 # Creating Server TCP listening socket 192.34.62.56​​:6379: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redis will never change the maximum open files.

This is a OS configuration and it can be configured on a per user basis also. The error is descriptive and tells you: "increase 'ulimit -n'"

You can refer to this blog post on how to increase the maximum open files descriptors:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Answer (score 67):

Well, it's a bit late for this post, but since I just spent a lot of time(the whole night) to configure a new redis server 3.0.6 on ubuntu 16.04. I think I should just write down how I do it so others don't have to waste their time...

For a newly installed redis server, you are probably going to see the following issues in redis log file which is **/var/log/redis/redis-server.log**

**Maximum Open Files**

```
3917:M 16 Sep 21:59:47.834 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
3917:M 16 Sep 21:59:47.834 # Redis can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
3917:M 16 Sep 21:59:47.834 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
```

I have seen a lot of posts telling you to modify

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
redis soft nofile 10000
redis hard nofile 10000
```

or

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
fs.file-max = 100000
```

*That might work in ubuntu 14.04, but it certainly not works in ubuntu 16.04.* I guess it has something to do with changing from upstart to systemd, but I am no expert of linux kernel!

To fix this you have to do it the **systemd** way

```
/etc/systemd/system/redis.service
[Service]
...
User=redis
Group=redis
# should be fine as long as you add it under [Service] block
LimitNOFILE=65536
...
```

**Then you must daemon reload and restart the service**

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart redis.service
```

To check if it works, try to cat proc limits

```
cat /run/redis/redis-server.pid
cat /proc/PID/limits
```

and you will see

```
Max open files            65536                65536                files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
```

At this stage, the maximum open file is solved.

**Socket Maximum Connection**

```
2222:M 16 Sep 20:38:44.637 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
```

**Memory Overcommit**

```
2222:M 16 Sep 20:38:44.637 # Server started, Redis version 3.0.6
2222:M 16 Sep 20:38:44.637 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
```

Since these two are related, we will solve it at once.

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf

# Add at the bottom of file
vm.overcommit_memory = 1
net.core.somaxconn=1024
```

Now for these configs to work, you need to reload the config

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

**Transparent Huge Pages**

```
1565:M 16 Sep 22:48:00.993 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
```

To permanently solve this, follow the log's suggestion, and modify rc.local

```
sudo vi /etc/rc.local

if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
    echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
```

This require you to **reboot**, backup your data or do anything you need before you actually do it!!

```
sudo reboot
```

Now check you redis log again, you should have a redis server without any errors or warnings.

Comment: thanks so much~ I find and try the same old  solution and in vain all night~you save my another night

Comment: About THP, if you are on Centos 7, you can follow this guide:
https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-disable-transparent-huge-pages-thp/

Comment: THP/Ubuntu 18: Sometimes redis loads before rc.local. Solution: In file `/etc/default/grub.d/no_thp.cfg` add the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT transparent_hugepage=never"`.
Then run `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need this command in console:

```
sudo ulimit -n 65535
```

Comment: try to edit the .bashrc file vi /root/.bashrc and add the following line:
# vi /root/.bashrc
ulimit -u unlimited

Comment: Also you can read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux

Comment: This won't persist after a reboot.