# Redis service automatically stops after few minutes of running

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

On my Ubuntu machine, redis server was running fine and suddenly it stops. After I started it, again it automatically stops after few minutes. So I start again, and so on. Why is this happening?

Here are the logs when I start redis:

21479:C 29 Apr 21:59:10.986 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo

21479:C 29 Apr 21:59:10.987 # Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=21479, just started

21479:C 29 Apr 21:59:10.987 # Configuration loaded

21480:M 29 Apr 21:59:10.990 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).

21480:M 29 Apr 21:59:10.991 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.

21480:M 29 Apr 21:59:10.992 # Server initialized

21480:M 29 Apr 21:59:14.588 * DB loaded from disk: 3.596 seconds

21480:M 29 Apr 21:59:14.591 * Ready to accept connections

Comment: Did you check logs ? Please attach it to question. It may help to identify problem.

Comment: @Ersoy I have shared logs, please check

Comment: Can you follow the steps listed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46255542/2188922