# How to Handle Multiple Request for a Particular API in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, jmeter

I have developed a web application using laravel , This Application consists API for Device Registeration. In order to Test this Application I used Apache JMeter to hit the API. Initially I send 500 request at a time to API using Apache JMeter(By creating threads) and application woked fine , But if I send 2000 request at a time to API only 1500 requests are being handled by laravel application.

So is there any configuration in Laravel to handle multiple request for particular API ??

API -

```
Route::post('device', 'DeviceManagementController@device');
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Any Inputs .....??

Comment: Same problem here, no solution found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129065/laravel-api-speed-too-slow/40129979?noredirect=1#comment67530336_40129979

Comment: Hi, apart from laravel you have to do some server configuration like in ubuntu you have to configure max number of open file limit  refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux . For windows also you to do some configuration Refer this link - http://microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.wininet.narkive.com/lAw5Ob1b/httpsendrequest-error-12002-internet-timeout it may be helpful for you :)