# Laravel API speed (too slow)

Tags: api, laravel, post, httprequest, rate-limiting

i'm trying to develop an API to store alarms coming from several applications into a database. I'm developing the api with Laravel.

I've made a C program which makes multiple post requests to the API in order to see how many request can the laravel api process.

I have the following route in api.php

```
Route::post('/alarm', 'Api\v1\AlarmController@store');
```

In my controller i have made the store function which stores the alarm values received in the post request into the database

```
function store(Request $request)
    {

        $content = $request->getContent();

       $json_content = json_decode($content);

        $id = $this->alarm_model->newAlarm($json_content);

        echo '{ "result": '.$id.', "msg":'.$content.' }';

    }
```

Then i have a Alarm model which stores the json values in the database alarm table.

If i make 1000 requests it is not able to process all of them. I get HttpSendRequest Error : 12002 Internet Timeout

Am I doing something wrong? How many requests per second allows Laravel framework?

Answer (score 1):

There's no limit, *as far as i know*, it all depends on your environment, if it's a small server i doubt it would be able to handle 1000 requests per second.

What you could do instead is make use of [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#connections-vs-queues)

What i think is happening on your end is that your server gets too busy when trying to complete the 1000 requests at once. This results in the server responding with the "I'm Busy" signal.

But with a queue you could limit the pressure on the server and make it happen over the course of a few minutes?

**How To:**

1. Create a Job `php artisan make:job ProcessAlarms`
2. In the Job's Handle method you put the logic to save the Alarm
3. Then in your Controller's `store` method use this `dispatch(new ProcessAlarm($data_you_want_to_pass));`

Comment: The thing is that if i do the same with a simple php (post request to a simple php which stores data in database) the server is able to process the 1000 request. 

So I don't know if i'm doing something wrong in laravel or if laravel gets the server busy.

Comment: Well Laravel goes through quite a bit in it's request cycle, so there's a big difference when going through 1 php file with "simple" SQL calls and then going through an entire application life cycle.

Comment: 1000 request in a CPU i5-2430 2.4GHz and 8Gb of RAM under Win7 is too much?

Comment: You could also take a look at Lumen, a lightweight variant of Laravel trimmed down exactly for faster API's