# beanstalkd - too many open files error

Tags: centos7, beanstalkd

> service beanstalkd status
>   in centos 7

beanstalkd[1375]: /usr/bin/beanstalkd: prot.c:1919 in h_accept: accept(): Too many open files

Of I restart beanstalkd service this error comes after 5 hrs

Anyone help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ran out of sockets.

This could be because:

1) Your application opened too many sockets. You can raise this limit via `ulimit` or similar.

2) You are leaking open connections. It is possible that your application is not closing requests in certain cases, causing your machine to run out of sockets. If this is the case, eventually you will hit the limit even if you raise it.

Some more information: [How do I change the number of open files limit in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux).

Comment: Thank u @arboreal84.
I'm new to beanstalkd. Can you tell me how to fix this issue in beanstalkd.
I increased the ulimit by 
> ulimit -n 4096

Comment: If by increasing the `ulimit` you still run out of connections, try to see why there are so many open files or connections: `netstat -a` will list all open sockets.

Comment: I used nohup php. Now it is working fine.
Thank you.