# Moving a very large MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

Trying to move a MongoDB database with a little over 100 million documents. Moving it from server in AWS to server in GCP. Tried `mongodump` - which worked, but `mongorestore` keeps breaking with an error -

```
error running create command: 24: Too many open files
```

How can this be done?

Don't want to transfer by creating a script on AWS server to fetch each document and push to an API endpoint on GCP server because it will take too long.

Edit (adding more details)
Already tried setting `ulimit -n` to unlimited. Doesn't work as GCP has a hardcoded limit that cannot be modified.

Comment: Also a manual section [Unix `ulimit` Settings](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/) and obtainable directly from searching https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+too+many+open+files

Comment: Actually, the question suggested is around indexing - a task far less intensive than mongorestore. Also, the ulimit on GCP cannot be modified beyond a limit and the restore processing is maxing it out (due to size of the database).

So neither the question is duplicate, nor is the solution give by @NeilLunn workable.

However, the solution given by glitch might work. Will try that and report here.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are hitting the `ulimit` for your user. This is likely a function of some or all of the following:

- Your user having the default `ulimit` (probably 256 or 1024 depending on the OS)
- The size of your DB, MongoDB's use of memory mapped files can result in a large number of open files during the restore process
- The way in which you are running `mongorestore` can increase the concurrency thereby increasing the number of file handles which are open concurrently

You can address the number of open files allowed for your user by invoking `ulimit -n <some number>` to increase the limit for your current shell. The number you choose cannot exceed the hard limit configured on your host. You can also change the ulimit permanently, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux#34645). This is the **root cause** fix but it is possible that your ability to change the `ulimit` is constrained by AWS so you might want to look at reducing the concurrency of your `mongorestore` process by tweaking the following settings:

> **--numParallelCollections** int
>
> Default: 4
>
> Number of collections mongorestore should restore in parallel.
>
> **--numInsertionWorkersPerCollection** int
>
> Default: 1
>
> Specifies the number of insertion workers to run concurrently per collection.

If you have chosen values for these other than 1 then you could reduce the concurrency (and hence the number of concurrently open file handles) by setting them as follows:

```
--numParallelCollections=1 --numInsertionWorkersPerCollection=1
```

Naturally, this will increase the run time of the restore process but it might allow you to sneak under the currently configured `ulimit`. Although, just to reiterate; the root cause fix is to increase the `ulimit`.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still getting same error after a few collections are restored.

Comment: Ok, well that was only ever a hopeful solution. Since your hands are tied with respect to increasing the `ulimit` I don't think you'll be able to use `mongorestore` to restore a database of that size :(

Comment: hmm .... will go the API transfer route. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: These two options --numParallelCollections=1 --numInsertionWorkersPerCollection=1  did not even work for me.