# Log4j2 Too many files open

Tags: java, log4j2

This is my log4j2 config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="WARN">
        <Appenders>
            <RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender" fileName="logs/app.log"
                         filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%d [%t] %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue} %msg%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                </Policies>
            </RollingFile>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

I getting an error saying Too many open files.

2018-06-28 14:46:54,014 Thread-0 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender RollingFileAppender org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: Error reading folder logs/2018-06 logs/2018-06: Too many open files

Comment: It probably means that your system cannot handle that many simultaneously open files.

Comment: You're mixing patterns: `$${date:yyyy-MM}` and `%d{MM-dd-yyyy}`. Shouldn't the second be `$${date:MM-dd-yyyy}`?

Comment: @Andreas i think it wouldn't help with my main problem

Comment: Try with `lsof -p <PID>` to check what are the opened files and count them.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz can it also refer to TCP connections when it says too many files open

Comment: yes, **everything** in Linux is a file.

Comment: so it showed a lot of TCP connections and I am trying to do testing with over 3000 threads firing request at the same time to my server

Comment: It's known limit to open files in Linux. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645/2834978)'s a good answer on how to fix it, temporarily and permanently.