# Nodemon Error: "System limit for number of file watchers reached"

Tags: node.js, graphql, nodemon

I'm learning [GraphQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphQL) and am using `prisma-binding` for GraphQL operations. I'm facing this `nodemon` error while I'm starting my Node.js server and its giving me the path of schema file which is auto generated by a `graphql-cli`. What is this error all about?

Error:

> Internal watch failed: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/media/rehan-sattar/Development/All projects/GrpahQl/graph-ql-course/graphql-prisma/src/generated

Comment: This is the linux ulimit error see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux

Comment: Tried this! Getting the same error again!

Comment: You are probably watching too many files. Maybe it's including the nod_modules directory as well?

Comment: `node_modules`  are essential because all the packages are there. I've tried to kill the previous processes running on the port of my server, it worked for me but I don't know how long it will take now :D

Answer (score 607, accepted):

#### Updated (05/2023)

There are some tips in the comments and I brought them to update this question. If you're facing this problem, then you are probably using a Linux distro and your project is hitting your system's file watchers limit.

Check your current inotify file watch limit by executing:

```bash
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

You can set a new limit temporarily with:

```bash
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=131070
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Or you can set a permanent limit:

```bash
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches= 131070 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Here we are setting 131070 file limit (as suggested by @Dmitriy in the comments). If this limit doesn't works for your system you can twice this number.

[This documentation](https://github.com/guard/listen/blob/fd85e1cb2375767e3cbc4b5743ff50061e8a6c75/README.md#the-technical-details) provides more technical details.

#### Old answer

If you are using Linux, your project is hitting your system's file watchers limit

To fix this, on your terminal, try:

```bash
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: use `sysctl --system` to reload for more recent systems

Comment: is there any other implications that we must know when we do this? I knew this helps solve the issue, I tried it myself. But I am a bit skeptic what possible side effects this fix can cause.

Comment: @Aldee about the technical implications of this change I recommend checking this wiki: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details

Comment: This also worked out a lot of issues with npm plugins. thx

Comment: Thank you! I had the same error on a React project I have just created and that has fixed it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend increasing it so much if you're not sure how many are in use. Check the number in use with the following `find /proc/*/fd -user "$USER" -lname anon_inode:inotify -printf '%hinfo/%f\n' 2>/dev/null | xargs cat | grep -c '^inotify'`

Comment: I actually have `max_user_watches` 4288 and excluded in `nodemonconfig` in `package.json` `.git` and `node_modules`. I wonder why there are so many files still which lead to the error.

Comment: Default value (on Ubuntu 21) was 65535 and setting it to just twice that value (131070) fixed the Node JS issues for me. So according to the principle of minimizing side effects, it is worth trying smaller increments before going all the way to 500k.

Comment: Note that changing `/etc/sysctl.conf` may result in your change conflicting with or being overwritten by an OS upgrade, depending on your distribution. Better is to use a separate file in `/etc/sysctl.d/`, as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411444/107294).

Comment: Doesn't work for me sadly!

Comment: This helped me out in a situation where I was upgrading `Laravel 8` > `Laravel 9` and swapping out `Laravel Mix` for `vite` & `Laravel Vite`. The `vite build` command worked fine, but `vite` caused the `ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached`. Running the above command fixed `vite`, and I didn't have to reboot my machine, or my hosts!

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, I had to name the file `50-user-watches.conf` to make sure it got priority. To confirm the priority of what setting is being applied, run `sudo sysctl --system | grep max_user_watches -B2` and you'll see what setting is applied last and by which file.

Comment: The "technical implications" link above from @IsacMoura can now be found here: https://github.com/guard/listen/blob/fd85e1cb2375767e3cbc4b5743ff50061e8a6c75/README.md#the-technical-details

Comment: Folks, thanks for the comments. I updated this question following the suggestions. 500K of limit is a huge limit (even though the documentation suggest that size) and I updated following the suggestion of @Dmitriy

Comment: To "twice" a number, you double it and add 1.  `twice(x): 2x + 1`

Comment: This works for me, without restarting my ubuntu system.

Answer (score 78):

You need to increase the [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) watchers limit for users of your system. You can do this from the command line with:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000
```

That will persist only until you reboot, though. To make this permanent, add a file named `/etc/sysctl.d/10-user-watches.conf` with the following contents:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 100000
```

After making the above (or any other) change, you can reload the settings from all [sysctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl) configuration files in `/etc` with `sudo sysctl --system`. (On older systems you may need to use `sudo sysctl -p` instead.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked for me!! But where i have to add this file?

Comment: @RehanSattar Create a file `/etc/sysctl.d/10-user-watches.conf` and in it put `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 100000`.

Comment: Putting this here for completeness `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/10-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl -p`.

Comment: use `sysctl --system` to reload for more recent systems

Comment: Is there a way to see the current value before updating it (eg to double the current value instead of using an arbitrary 100000)? Edit: it is `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches`, on my machine default is 65536

Comment: Also this answer seems to not work for Linux (either outdated or Mac-only?), see answer below using `/etc/sysctl.conf` file instead

Comment: @EricBurel It's a Linux-only answer; I've never tried this on Mac. However, the option to reload all sysctl files was incorrect; I've fixed it.

Answer (score 75):

I sometimes get this issue when working with Visual Studio Code on my [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) machine.

In my case the following workaround helps:

Stop the watcher, close Visual Studio Code, start the watcher, and open Visual Studio Code again.

Comment: That's right! Because of VSCode. It should be autosave mode.

Comment: this worked for me; developing with ember-cli

Comment: As w/my focal box this happens intermittently and the VSCode restart is the fix w/out fiddling w/max-_user_watches. 
(note: When it is working, I typically see watchers in use well below 7k)

Comment: I think I have the same problem but with my Nextcloud client. How do I stop and restart the watcher? I couldn't search for the right term to get a proper answer.

Comment: Same situation (Ubuntu/VS Code). It might help to close any folders in the folder tree that you're not currently working on, maybe even hiding the explorer altogether (not sure if VS Code has watchers for currently visible files and folders in Explorer).

Comment: Same here with web storm in JetBrains (Ubuntu), restart/invalidating cache did the trick.

Answer (score 30):

In order to test the changes, I temporary set the parameter with the value 524288.

```
sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

Then I proceed to validate:

```
npm run serve
```

And the problem was solved. In order to make it permanent, you should try to add a line in the file "/etc/sysctl.conf" and then restart the [sysctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl) service:

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf | tail -n 2
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288

sudo systemctl restart systemd-sysctl.service
```

Comment: This hint for test temporarily is priceless. Thank you

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. However, mine was coming from [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack). Thankfully, they had a great solution [on their site](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/):

> For some systems, watching many files can result in a lot of CPU or memory usage. It is possible to exclude a huge folder like node_modules using a regular expression:

#### File *webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/
  }
};
```

Answer (score 10):

This is *a* problem of [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) (inode notify) in the Linux kernel, so you can resolve it by using this command:

1. For a temporary solution until rebooting the pc, use the following command

   ```
   sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000
   ```
2. A permanent solution: To make this permanent, add a file named */etc/sysctl.d/10-user-watches.conf* with the following contents:

   ```
   fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 10000
   ```

After making the change, reload the settings from all [sysctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl) configuration files in */etc* with `sudo sysctl -p`.

Comment: Missing a zero in item 2

Answer (score 4):

In my case, while I'm doing the nodemon command on the Linux server, I have my Visual Studio Code open (SSH to the server). So based on [Juri Sinitson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930305/nodemon-error-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached/55027686#55027686), I just close Visual Studio Code and run the *nodemon* command again. And it works.

My *nodemon* command:

`nodemon server.js` via npm start

Comment: Worked for me as well. I had basically two VSCode open. Closing the previous one solved the issue.

Comment: this surprisingly worked!

Answer (score 3):

It can be hard to know how much to increase the number of watchers by. So, here's a utility to double the number of watchers:

```sh
function get_inode_watcher_count() {
  find /proc/*/fd -user "$USER" -lname anon_inode:inotify -printf '%hinfo/%f\n' 2>/dev/null | 
  xargs cat | 
  grep -c '^inotify'
}

function set_inode_watchers() {
  sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches="$1"
}

function double_inode_watchers() {
  watcher_count="$(get_inode_watcher_count)"
  set_inode_watchers "$((watcher_count * 2))"

  if test "$1" = "-p" || test "$1" = "--persist"; then
    echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches = $((watcher_count * 2))" > /etc/sysctl.d/10-user-watches.conf
  fi
}

# Usage
double_inode_watchers
# to make the change persistent
double_inode_watchers --persist
```

Answer (score 3):

I think most answers given here are correct, but using the [systemctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Core_components_and_libraries) command to restart my service solved the problem for me. Check the command below:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-sysctl.service
```

Comment: There is nothing in the question about the platform. Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73668928/edit) the Linux distribution, version, etc. to the answer (but ********************* ***without*** ********************* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)?

Answer (score 2):

I use Vite alongside with Python and its venv module, and I encountered the same error because of a large venv folder (10k files)
Vite config allows ignoring directories from file watcher, so with venv ignored, the error was gone.

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    watch: {
      ignored: ['**/venv/**'],
    }
  },
})
```

[Vite docs](https://v2.vitejs.dev/config/#server-watch)

Answer (score 2):

```
 sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=131070


 sudo sysctl -p
```

If this limit doesn't works for your system you can twice this number.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow answers such as this one:

[cjs'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411444/9316077)

Or:

[Isac Moura's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55543310/9316077)

And for latest Ubuntu versions, run `sudo sysctl --system` to read these settings anew.

However, in my case, my changes to these configuration files were not picked up, because I had already tweaked these settings a while ago... and forgot about it. And I had placed the conflicting configuration file in the wrong place.

According to `man sysctl.d`, these settings can be placed in `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf`, `/run/sysctl.d/*.conf` and `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf`.

In my case I had two files:

```
/etc/sysctl.d/10-user-watches.conf
/usr/lib/sysctl.d/30-tracker.conf     <<< Older file, with lower limit
```

Due to the naming convention, my older file was read last, and took precedence.

Answer (score -4):

On Linux, I've actually run with sudo.
`sudo npm start`

Comment: This will often work because root usually has a much higher inotify watch limit than regular users, but it's a _very_ bad idea to be running things as root when they don't need to be. See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411444/107294) for how to change the user limit.