# error in react.js when clicking npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

first of all I created a todo app in react.js with the command: npx create-react-app app_name

after running the command npm start, it displayed this errors to me:

[image]

[image]

after that I found a log file wich has all these lines that I didn't understand anything from them:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/amarmahdi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/amarmahdi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle inventory@0.1.0~prestart: inventory@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle inventory@0.1.0~start: inventory@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle inventory@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle inventory@0.1.0~start: PATH: /home/amarmahdi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/amarmahdi/developement/reactTutorial/inventory/node_modules/.bin:/home/amarmahdi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin:/home/amarmahdi/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle inventory@0.1.0~start: CWD: /home/amarmahdi/developement/reactTutorial/inventory
10 silly lifecycle inventory@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle inventory@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle inventory@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: inventory@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/home/amarmahdi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/home/amarmahdi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid inventory@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/amarmahdi/developement/reactTutorial/inventory
16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-74-generic
17 verbose argv "/home/amarmahdi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node" "/home/amarmahdi/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error inventory@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the inventory@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

for the operating system I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and for node I'm using node version manager, with node version 14.17.0.

I hope that there will be some answers about this question.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930305/nodemon-error-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Linux internally observes the number of times file is watched.
Well, you can override the limit by doing

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

in your terminal.

Comment: copy paste from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930305/nodemon-error-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached