# React App Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi3

I have setup a new blank react  app.

After installing few node modules I got this error

```
**System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/pi/food/food/public'**
```

Comment: Can you post the context of this error, especially which process spitted this out - it means that a process is trying to subscribe to too many file modification notifications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodemon Error: System limit for number of file watchers reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930305/nodemon-error-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached)