# node:internal/errors:484 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-sail

When i run `vendor/bin/sail npm run dev` i got this error. Can anyone explain why that is happening ? i am setting up aws server for my laravel website

```
  LARAVEL v9.46.0  plugin v0.7.3

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost
node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs/exception-report.stub'                                                                                                                                       eption-report.stub'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (node:internal/fs/watchers:244:19)
    at Object.watch (node:fs:2315:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:48596:17)
    at setFsWatchListener (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:48643:15)
    at NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:48798:14)
    at NodeFsHandler._handleFile (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:48862:23)
    at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:49104:21)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:50296:10)
    at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (file:///var/www/html/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:49112:18) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs/exception-report.stub',
  filename: '/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/stubs/exception-report.stub'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

i have tried `npm audit fix --force` but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command on my host (not on Sail shell) solved it:

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=131070
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55543310/296540