# Spring Integration RecursiveDirectoryScanner gives too many files open exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, file-handling

I am using Spring Integration RecursiveDirectoryScanner to scan a directory recursively to process the incoming file that will be placed under the configured directory (/home/test).

I am frequently getting the below error:

```
    ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /home/test: Too many open files
        at org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveDirectoryScanner.listFiles(RecursiveDirectoryScanner.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.scanInputDirectory(FileReadingMessageSource.java:387)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.doReceive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:361)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.doReceive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:90)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:134)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:224)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /home/test: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:427)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:300)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:72)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3574)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveDirectoryScanner.listFiles(RecursiveDirectoryScanner.java:73)
```

My Spring Integration flow is as below:

**Configuration in XML**

```
 <task:executor id="pollerPool"
        pool-size="${pollerThreadPoolSize}"
        queue-capacity="${pollerThreadQueueCapacity}" rejection-policy="ABORT" />

    <task:executor id="fileHandlerPool"
        pool-size="${fileHandlerPoolSize}"
        queue-capacity="${fileHandlerPoolThreadQueueCapacity}" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />


     <bean id="iFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.ChainFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
             <list>
                  <bean id="lastModifiedFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.LastModifiedFileListFilter">
                     <property name="age" value="120" />
                  </bean>
                 <ref bean="acceptOnceFileListFilter"/>

                 <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter">
                    <constructor-arg value="^.*\.(txt|csv|xls|xlsx|asc)$"/>
                 </bean>

            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>

     <bean id="acceptOnceFileListFilter" name="acceptOnceFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter" primary="true" />

     <bean id="recursiveDirectoryScanner" class="org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveDirectoryScanner">
        <property name="filter" ref="iFilter" />
        <property name="locker" ref="nioFileLocker" />
     </bean>

    <bean id="nioFileLocker" class="org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker" />

    <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="fileSource" channel="fileReceivedChannel" auto-startup="true"
        directory="file:${polling.directory}" 
        scanner="recursiveDirectoryScanner"  >
        <int:poller task-executor="pollerPool"
            fixed-rate="${pollerFixedRate}"
            receive-timeout="${pollerReceiveTimeout}">
        </int:poller>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Dynamic parameters are as below:

- polling.directory=/home/test 
  pollerThreadPoolSize=1
  pollerThreadQueueCapacity=10 
  pollerFixedRate=5000
  pollerReceiveTimeout=5000 
  fileHandlerPoolSize=2
  fileHandlerPoolThreadQueueCapacity=100

EDIT:

I do unlock file in a service activator that comes in to picture when a file is picked. I get some information from file and unlock it.

```
@Autowired
  NioFileLocker nioFileLocker;

   protected void doTransform(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
  MessageBuilder<File> payload = (MessageBuilder<File>) message.getPayload();
    File inFile = payload.getPayload();
   try {
      nioFileLocker.unlock(inFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("file not unlock");
    }
 }
```

Is there any issue with the configuration ? How do I make sure this exception never appear again ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What OS is this running on?

Comment: It is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux

Comment: Current limit is 1024. By increasing limit I am not sure if it will not happen again. What can be the root cause of the issue ?

Comment: It's just that. Some programs open many files (which is not just files in linux). The defaults aren't always practical for some servers. You probably need to increase the limit, but you just evaluate it before making a decision...

Comment: Thanks ernest_k for the quick response. I will check that too. However, if you find any other solution let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can we see `cause by` of that exception? I wonder which part of the `Files.walk()` is failing...

Comment: @Artem: I have edited my question and added caused by.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to test your solution without `NioFileLocker`. Doesn't look like you are using it for unlocking files, but the `lock(File fileToLock)` really keeps some file marker in OS.

On the other hand the file locker doesn't work reliable on UNIX systems. It still allows an access to files. At least for reading.

For better exclusive file access I would recommend to use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` with the external `MetadataStore` instead of in memory `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. This way only one instance of your application will get access to the file and it won't be processed again at all.

Comment: I do actually unlock the file. I have added that bit of code also in the question in EDIT section.

Comment: How does it work without locker at all? Since your dir is recursive and you have a lot of threads to process, that indeed might be the case that locker is a bottleneck for your solution.