# multiprocessing keeps raising "OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files"

Tags: python, multiprocessing

A lot of answers say that I should put `pool` under a `with` statement, which I already have. I failed to find any related topics, let alone available solutions.

p.s.: I am spawning 100 processes (the `n_games` in the code) on a 48-core CPU in Linux.

The code is basically

```
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() - 1) as pool:

    jobs = [pool.apply_async(
        game.start_play,
        (player1, player2, i % 2, 0)
    ) for i in range(n_games)]

    for job in jobs:
        win_cnt[job.get()] += 1

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Check how many files your processes may open with [`ulimit -n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux/). You may need to increase that.

Comment: @metatoaster It says 1024. I don't know if it's sufficient.