# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files; in python; difficult to debug

Tags: python, file-handling, with-statement

I am running code which after sometimes hours, sometimes minutes fails with the error

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

And I have real trouble debugging this. The error itself is always triggered by the marked line in the code snippet below

```
try:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        contents = f.read()       <----- error triggered here
except OSError as e:
    print("e = ", e)
    raise
else:
    # other stuff happens
```

However, I can't see any problem in this part of the code (right?) so I guess that other parts of the code don't close files properly. However, while I do open files quite a bit, I always open them with the 'with' statement, and my understanding is that even if an error occurs the files will be closed (right?). So another part of my code looks like this

```
    try:
        with tarfile.open(filename + '.tar') as tar:
            tar.extractall(path=target_folder)
    except tarfile.ReadError as e:
        print("e = ", e)
    except OSError as e:
        print("e = ", e)
    else:
        # If everything worked, we are done
        return
```

The code above does run into a ReadError quite frequently, but even if that happens, the file should be closed, right? So I just don't understand how I can run into too many open files? Sorry this is not reproducible for you, since I can't debug it enough, I just fishing for some tips here, since I am lost. Any help is appreciated...

Edit: I am on a macbook. Here is the output of ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1418
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Following the suggestion by @sj95126 I changed the code concerning the tar file to something which ensures that the file is closed

```
try:
    tar = tarfile.open(filename + '.tar')
    tar.extractall(path=target_folder)
except tarfile.ReadError as e:
    print("tarfile.ReadError e = ", e)
except OSError as e:
    print("e = ", e)
else:
    # If everything worked, we are done
    return
finally:
    print("close tar file")
    try:
        tar.close()
    except:
        print("file already closed")
```

but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: if you are using linux, please tell me the value of `file locks` using `ulimit -a` in cmd.

Comment: Normally you're right that a ```with``` should result in the file being closed; however, there's always the possibility of a bug in the managing object. A ```tarfile``` object has to close the file, the ```with``` isn't going to reach through to the ```file``` object and do it. Just for testing, try adding a ```finally``` clause to the ```try``` and explicitly call ```tar.close()```, and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks all for the comments. @alexzander I added the ulimit -a above.

Comment: @sj95126 this is a very good point. I will test your suggestion.

Comment: @Carcigenicate there are many more cases where I work with files, but they have all the same syntax and they are used sequentially, not in parallel. I am pretty sure it must be my code since I get this error even if I stop all other of my programs.

Comment: okey then im gonna make my comment into answer, for people who need guidance.

Comment: `ls -l /proc/PID/fd`, with the PID of the Python process, will let you see what the open files _are_; it'l be much easier to identify the code that's supposed to be responsible for closing them after you've determined that.

Answer (score 0):

on `unix/linux` systems there is a command with which you can check the total number of `file locks` or `open files` limit using `ulimit -a`. in @carl's situation the output was:

```sh
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1418
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

as you can see the `open files` or `file locks` is equal to `256`:

```sh
open files                      (-n) 256
```

which is a very `small` value

@carl's archive was at least containing more than 256 files; so python was opening each file using a file handler, which then results in a `system file lock` (in order to open a file on a system you need a file lock, like a pointer to that file; to access data, do whatever you want)

the solution is to make `open files` value to `unlimited` or to a `very big` number.

according to this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8285278/12172291) this is how to you can change the limit

Comment: But I always close files and always have only one file open at a time. So I don't quite understand why I am running into this issue. There must be something in my code not closing files properly and I rather find this bug than just setting this limit to a larger number.